# Archive page for custom taxonomy grouped by month

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-get-archives

I am working on archive page of custom taxonomy of custom post types. I need to show archives by month of particular taxonomy.

For retrieving post in particular taxonomy by month. However, I have used following code.

```
function my_custom_post_archive_where($where,$args){  
    $post_type  = isset($args['post_type'])  ? $args['post_type']  : 'post';  
    $where = "WHERE post_type = '$post_type' AND post_status = 'publish'";
    return $where;  
}

add_filter( 'getarchives_where','my_custom_post_archive_where',10,2);
```

But above filter gives all post in certain post type. I only need posts in particular taxonomy and also its respective pages.

For example:

Archives:

July 2015
June 2015

How can I do it? Please anyone suggests me, as I am really trapped here.

Thanks in advance :).

Comment: This is just a normal taxonomy.php template?

Comment: I tried creating archive-customPostType.php but its not working.

Comment: Its not taxonomy template, that's not working @PieterGoosen

Comment: Where is this code currently

Comment: This code is in function.php and I have include it as "wp_get_archives($args)" in taxonomy page.

Comment: I have reread your question, is this for a term of a specific taxonomy, or the taxonomy itself, because taxonomies don't have archives, just their terms. In anycase you can use template `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term}` with the default loop. This should display posts from that specific term in default order by date in descending order. You will then just need to display the mont names accordingly

Comment: Oh according to my client's need. I have to show Archives as July 2015 for a specific taxonomy. Otherwise, I have displayed page by using taxonomy-{$taxonomy}-{$term}. I am just stuck over here, any suggestions please..

Comment: Is this for a widget or som, like the archive widget. Sorry, but I cannot place your code. There are missing context here. That code makes more sense in a widget or something

Answer (score 1):

Hey anyways I found with an exact answer which works as a charm. I hope it would be helpful to someone so I am posting it over here.

First you need to add the following code in function.php

```
/**
 * Custom post type date archives
 */

/**
 * Custom post type specific rewrite rules
 * @return wp_rewrite             Rewrite rules handled by Wordpress
 */
function cpt_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = cpt_generate_date_archives('your-post-type', $wp_rewrite);
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'cpt_rewrite_rules');

/**
 * Generate date archive rewrite rules for a given custom post type
 * @param  string $cpt        slug of the custom post type
 * @return rules              returns a set of rewrite rules for Wordpress to handle
 */
function cpt_generate_date_archives($cpt, $wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();

    $post_type = get_post_type_object($cpt);
    $slug_archive = $post_type->has_archive;
    if ($slug_archive === false) return $rules;
    if ($slug_archive === true) {
        $slug_archive = $post_type->name;
    }

    $dates = array(
        array(
            'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})",
            'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum', 'day')),
        array(
            'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})",
            'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum')),
        array(
            'rule' => "([0-9]{4})",
            'vars' => array('year'))
        );

    foreach ($dates as $data) {
        $query = 'index.php?post_type='.$cpt;
        $rule = $slug_archive.'/'.$data['rule'];

        $i = 1;
        foreach ($data['vars'] as $var) {
            $query.= '&'.$var.'='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
            $i++;
        }

        $rules[$rule."/?$"] = $query;
        $rules[$rule."/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = $query."&feed=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
        $rules[$rule."/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = $query."&feed=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
        $rules[$rule."/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$"] = $query."&paged=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
    }
    return $rules;
}


/**
 * Get a montlhy archive list for a custom post type
 * @param  string  $cpt  Slug of the custom post type
 * @param  boolean $echo Whether to echo the output
 * @return array         Return the output as an array to be parsed on the template level
 */
function get_cpt_archives( $cpt, $echo = false )
{
    global $wpdb; 
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR($wpdb->posts.post_date), MONTH($wpdb->posts.post_date) ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC", $cpt);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if ( $results )
    {
        $archive = array();
        foreach ($results as $r)
        {
            $year = date('Y', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
            $month = date('F', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
            $month_num = date('m', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
            $link = get_bloginfo('siteurl') . '/' . $cpt . '/' . $year . '/' . $month_num;
            $this_archive = array( 'month' => $month, 'year' => $year, 'link' => $link );
            array_push( $archive, $this_archive );
        }

        if( !$echo )
            return $archive;
        foreach( $archive as $a )
        {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $a['link'] . '">' . $a['month'] . ' ' . $a['year'] . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit this line 
 $rules = cpt_generate_date_archives('your-post-type', $wp_rewrite);

change with your post type then on the page where you want to show archives for post type call it like this

```
<?php get_cpt_archives( 'your-post-type', true ); ?>
```

If you want to remove formatting such as li then simply use as below:

```
<?php get_cpt_archives( 'your-post-type' ); ?>
```

And don't forget you have to create an archive page like this

```
archive-{your-post-type}.php
```

That's it. Happy coding :)